# I can't figure out which SQL command to run for this task. I am using the sakila database for practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to provide a list of the “high interest” countries. A “high interest” country is defined as a country in which we have 20 or more customers. For each “high interest” country, list the country’s name and the number of customers in that “High Interest” country. I need to order the list by the number of customers in descending order.

Any ideas on how to get these results from the sakila database? Here's my SQL that I've written so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country.country, COUNT(customer.customer_id) AS customer_count
FROM customer
INNER JOIN address ON customer.address_id=address.address_id
INNER JOIN city ON address.city_id=city.city_id
INNER JOIN country ON city.country_id=country.country_id
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) >= 20
ORDER BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC;
```

Comment: I don't know the sakila database, but it seems you only miss the group by statement.
`GROUP BY country.country` just before the having-clause. I think you only got no errors because mysql is very 'tolerant' with columns not grouped or aggregated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's likely (though not impossible) that in lifetime of working with sql queries, you will never need to an aggregate function in conjunction with `SELECT DISTINCT` (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know the sakila database, but it seems you only miss the group by statement. GROUP BY country.country just before the having-clause. I think you only got no errors because mysql is very 'tolerant' with columns not grouped or aggregated.

This problem was solved by Turo's comment. Adding the GROUP BY statement displayed the results I needed.